# I can't access data from api in node js

Tags: node.js, api, axios, ejs

I'm trying to obtain data from an API with Axios and then pass it into an EJS template, but I'm not sure where the problem is!

Here is the code:

```
router.get("/", async (req, res, next) =>  
   
    try {
       const apiData = await axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/?key=API_KEY");         
       res.render('pages/home',{
           apiData: JSON.stringify(apiData),
       });
    }
    catch (err){
       console.log(err)
    }
});
```

EJS Template:

```
<% apiData.forEach(user => { %>
 <?= user.data.firstname ?> <br>
<% }) %>
```

**NB.** The API data from the URL are structured this way:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "total": 3,
    "data": [
        {
        "reference": "",     
        "firstname": "firstname",
        "lastname": "lastname",
        "email": "email@gmail.com",
        "mobile": "(011) 111-111",
        "avatar": "avatar.jpg",
        "is_active": 0,
        "is_verified": 0,
        "created_at": "2022-09-16T11:41:19.000Z",
        "validated_at": null
        },
        {
            .... 
        }
    ]
}
```

Important: Im new to node js, so forgive me if I'm mixing things up

Comment: I did try apiData.data but I got a bunch of error in ejs template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make three changes.

First, use `await` with your axios call.

Then, second don't use `JSON.stringify()` when passing data to your template.  Pass an actual Javascript object.

```
router.get("/", async (req, res, next) =>  
   
    try {
       const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/?key=API_KEY");         
       res.render('pages/home', {apiData: response.data});
    }
    catch (err){
       console.log(err)
       // send error response
       res.sendStatus(500);
    }
});
```

Then, third, use `apiData.data.forEach()` in your template because it's the `data` property that is the array, not the top level object.